# How to convert a number with more decimal places to the number as it shows on the screen?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I came across a situation where many results got many decimal places. For further calculations in my situation, I would just take the value as it shows on the screen and drop further digits. For example, I have `aa = Pi/2 // N`, which shows on my screen as `1.5708` while its actual value is `1.5707963267948966'`. I would like to have a process that turns this value `aa` with many digits to its approximation `bb` which would be just `1.5708`. I do not want to specify number of decimal places, but will take what appears on the screen (since other results may have a different number of decimal places). Also, this `bb` needs to be able for use towards further calculations, such that `bb + 1` will give me 2.5708 exactly.

Comment: You should perhaps know that the number of digits displayed by default is determined by `Options[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision]`, so you could just use `Round[]` along with that setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aa = Pi/2 // N;

bb = ToExpression[ToString[aa]]
```

> 1.5708

```
bb + 1
```

> 2.5708

Comment: I've long used the following which is similar to Chris's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have a process that turns this value aa with many
>   digits to its approximation bb which would be just 1.5708

If you mean here a "manual process", then you can do a "copy as plainText" -> "Paste"

[image]

Compare with what happens with a normal Copy-> Paste (on Windows: Crtl-C -> Ctlr-V)

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but I was looking for a function type of process. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I've long used the following which is similar to Chris Dengen's answer above. However the addition of NumberForm, InputForm and a parameter n make this a workhorse for me.

Why would I need this in Mathematica? One example. Suppose I do a model fit to data of lower precision and get back model parameters to 15 decimal points. No way. Using parameters in my model with that much precision conveys a lack of understanding on my part of the approximate nature of the model. And perhaps confuses the model user. So I convert the list of parameters using `sigFig` before embedding it in the model function that I deliver to a customer. (I have never understood why this isn't built-in to Mathematica.)

```
sigFig::usage = "sigFig[4.912238383] returns 4.91, sigFig[4.912238383,1] returns 5";

sigFig[x_, n_:3] := 
 ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[x, n], InputForm]];

test = sigFig[4.91223, #] & /@ Range[1, 20];
```